# Mysql group by aggregation sort and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to figure out a seemingly trivial SQL query.
For all users in the table I want to find the time and data for the row with the highest time (latest event).

The following almost solves it

```
SELECT user, MAX(time) as time FROM tasks GROUP BY user;
```

The problem is of course that the `data` column cannot be reduced. I think therefore I should use a WHERE or ORDER BY + LIMIT construction. But I am too far out of my domain here to know how this should be done properly. Any hints?

Note. It is not possible to use GROUP BY in this instance because I want to select on the table row ID, which cannot be aggregated, obviously.

```
-- MYSQL

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;

CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    time date NOT NULL,
    data varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tasks (user, time, data) VALUES
    ("Kalle", "1970-01-01", "old news"),
    ("Kalle", "2020-01-01", "latest shit"),
    ("Pelle", "1970-01-01", "regular data");

-- Expected output
-- +----+-------+------------+--------------+
-- | id | user  | time       | data         |
-- +----+-------+------------+--------------+
-- |  2 | Kalle | 2020-01-01 | latest shit  |
-- |  3 | Pelle | 1970-01-01 | regular data |
-- +----+-------+------------+--------------+
-- 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I am not putting in work in something that is closed. I would be happy to adapt the form of the Q if it would be accessible to others to learn from.

Comment: This question is closed, but _not_ deleted. Questions closed as duplicates (like this one) are often useful to future users since they provide additional search targets. If you have the above content in a file the only "work" you'd have to do is copy that text, [edit] this question, paste the text over the image, select the code again, and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: I updated the Q as suggested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.* 
from tasks t
where time = (select max(t1.time) from tasks t1 where t1.user = t.user)
```

This query would take advantage of a multi-column index on `(user, time)`.

In MySQL 8.0, you can also solve this top-1-per-group with window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by user order by time desc) rn from tasks t) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: would the multi-column index be preferable to using the Id column? Instead of using `where time = ...` use `where id = ...` and select the Id of the latest task for the user?

Comment: @user3504575: both options are OK, depending on how you define the *latest* task.